# Contract ending shortly before maternal leave

Tags: united-states, contracts, leave, pregnancy

I am an employee of a private company (I work in DC. The company is based / headquartered elsewhere.) on a three-year contract. It expires three weeks after I am expected to start maternity leave / [FMLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_and_Medical_Leave_Act_of_1993) / short term disability.

I did expect my contract to be extended this time. My contract has been renewed three times before. My reviews are exemplary. There is nothing negative in my file. My boss has said he’s happy with my performance.

We went through a sale a few months back— but we’ve hired more people so I know there isn’t any downsizing happening.

I think my contract will not be extended because I am pregnant. Does it matter since a contract is a contract and it's ending?

Is there any recourse to at least get it extended until the end of my short term disability?

Comment: Can you let us know roughly where you're located (country at least)?

Comment: Hi and welcome, OP. Can you add achievable goal? What do you want to happen?

Comment: Thanks @aaaaasaysreinstateMonica I had skimmed past that, looking for mention of a specific place.

Comment: If you were not pregnant would you expect the contract to be extended as it was before?

Comment: I think you should try to get some legal advice about this. I thik in my country, in this case your contraxt should officially be extended till the end of your maternity leave (not sure though)

Comment: Before you approach any other route, did you check directly with the manager responsible for extension and asked if they can extend it as long as you are capable for working? Did they already indicate pregnancy as a factor in this decision? If not, why are you thinking it would not be extended?

Comment: Can you clarify if you are an *employee* or *independent contractor*?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what your employment status is. Are you saying you are a W2 Temp/Seasonal directly with your place of day-to-day exmployment? Or is your employment agreement with a consulting/contracting firm, and you are W2 full time with them? Or are you an independent contractor? This is the most important thing.

Unless you are a W2 permanent employee of some company involved, in my opinion you will really struggle to prove a case - not only is the US a hard place to win such cases, but you are technically being compensated hourly if you are not W2 permanent.

Comment: Asking for clarification should be done in comments